# py sequence not returning results

Tags: python

I am trying a program in py where i have to compute the sequence [![enter image description here][1]][1]

until [![enter image description here][2]][2]

My code is:

```
def a(n):
    z=(n**10)
    return z


n=1
while a(n)<10:
    a(n)
    n+=1
    print(a(n))
```

But i get nothing in return. How off am I?

Comment: Why did the function change? The original post used a different sequence definition.

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop condition is not true on the first iteration so it never runs.

`abs(a(n)-a(n-1))` is 0.01 when n=1, which is not less than `10**-6`

Comment: thank you. However that is the statement i was given...

Comment: The constraint on your sequence is not true for small values of n. I suggest running it without the constraint to see where it starts decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your condition should be reversed, in that you want the `while` loop to continue until the condition becomes false. So, you can reverse the condition like this:

```
def a(n):
    z = (n**100/100**n)
    return z

n=1
while abs(a(n)-a(n-1)) > 10**-6:  # notice the inverted test
    print(n, a(n), abs(a(n)-a(n-1)))
    n+=1
```

To make the code a bit more readable at each iteration, this is another option:

```
while True:
    delta = abs(a(n) - a(n-1))
    print('Calculating ', n, delta) 
    if delta <= 10**-6:
        print('Last iteration on n=', n)
        break
    n += 1
```